# why can't I pull HTTP requests after configured controller in nest.js

Tags: javascript, nestjs

So, the person who left the company used Nest.js write this server side.
He has **auth.controller, auth.service,auth.module,auth-token,jwt.strategy and jwt-payload all set up well**, and I checked his module, everything is imported and the providers are being set up well.

But in front-end I do send HTTP request in any end point, I just always get code 404. 
 even if i wrote a simple end point like this :

```
  *@Get('/meow')
  toMeow(){
    return 'meow';
  }*
```

in his controller file, I still can't pull any HTTP request.

In his other folders controller ,I do can pull the HTTP request well with same address plus the routes

What's the reason for this?

Comment: You need to check where `@AuthGuard` is being used. Looks like its being registered as a GlobalGuard

Comment: Hi， AuthGuard is being used in a controller called User.controller, I only used it once for modify one of the function.

Answer (score 0):

My coworker solved it, I didnt register jwt.strategy to the Module